# Characteristic of a field is not equal to zero

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field such that for every $x \in F$ there exists a $k >0$ such that $x^k=1$. Does this imply that the characteristic of $F$ is strictly greater than zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  If the characteristic is zero then the [prime subfield](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSubfield.html) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, and this contains elements - e.g. 2 - whose nonzero powers are never equal to 1.

Answer (score 4):

Every field $F$ of characteristic $0$ contains (up to isomorphism) the field of rational numbers. If you take the rational number $\frac{1}{2}$, say, then there is no integer $k>0$ such that $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k = 1$.

For a finite field with $q$ (prime power) elements, one has $x^{q-1}=1$ for each element $x\ne 0$ and $x^q=x$ for each element $x$.